# In GIMP, how do I get the smudge/blur tools to work properly?

Tags: gimp, rgb, blur

I use the smudge tool very often in GIMP while painting. Unfortunately, the algorithm tends to generate a much darker version of what the smudged color ought to look like. For instance, a normal smudge on GIMP looks like this:

[image]

But I want the smudged color to be a lighter yellow, sort of like this:

[image]

In general all smudged colors appear darker and I understand this has something to with GIMP working with sRGB colors as opposed to RGB. But I'd really like to know what setting I need to tweak in GIMP to correct the smudge algorithm (maybe blur too, but I use smudge much more).

[ I assumed sRGB takes the square roots of the original value, so when the smudge tries to average colors between two pixels 'a' and 'b', it takes $ (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})/2 $, which is darker than $ sqrt(a/2 + b/2)^2 $. ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GIMP 2.10 or higher**

`Image > Precision > Linear Light`

**GIMP 2.8 or lower**

1. Download the color profile `sRGB-elle-V4-g10.icc` from e.g. [here](http://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/lab/sRGB-elle-V4-g10.icc).
2. `Image > Mode > Convert to Color Profile... > Select color profile from disk... > sRGB-elle-V4-g10.icc`

---

**Additional notes**

Store the color profile in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\spool\drivers\color` (Windows) `/Library/ColorSync/Profiles` (Mac OS X) `/usr/share/color/icc` (Linux) so it's next to the pre-installed ones. None of the pre-installed profiles seem to do linear light.

I tested this with brush, smudge and Gaussian blur and they all worked. However, the *preview* for Gaussian blur showed me the wrong (perceptual gamma) colors, but produced the right (linear light) result when *actually applied*!

I also recommend the YouTube video ["Computer Color is Broken"](https://pixls.us/articles/users-guide-to-high-bit-depth-gimp-2-9-2-part-2/) explaining the issue.

**Source**: "[Radiometrically correct editing](http://gimp.org/news/images/gimp-2-9-2/2015-11-27-openexr-32bit-float-mode.jpg)"

Comment: The newest stable package is GIMP 2.8 - 2.9.x are development versions. It is easy to build it yourself on any reasonably recent distro, and run it in addition to 2.8, though.

Comment: Regarding Mac color profiles: `~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles` is better if you don't need to install it for all users of the machine, or if you don't have administrator access.